# Fibration and a morphism which is homotopic to a fiber bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, complex-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a surjective holomorphic map between two compact complex manifolds. Suppose that $R^if_*\mathbb{Q}_X$ are locally constant sheaves over $Y$ for all $i$, and $f$ is homotopic to a $C^{\infty}$-fiber bundle.

Q: Is it true that $f$ is a fibration, in particular, all the fibers of $f$ are homotopic to each other?

Any related reference is wellcome.

Comment: One method of proof would be via Ehresmann's lemma, which says a proper surjective submersion is a fibration. The only non-obvious hypothesis to check is whether $f$ is a submersion. I do not immediately see a reason that this must happen from the condition on the $R^if_*\Bbb Q_X$, but perhaps someone else can fill in the details or provide a counterexample.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks! The Ehresmann's lemma says more: Proper surjective submersion is a $C^{\infty}$-fiber bundle not just a fibration.    Here I am asking whether $f$ is a fibration or not.

Comment: It's not clear what is the difference between fiber bundle and fibration in your wording. In AG, fibration allows degenerate fibers and fiber bundle is a fibration.